# WP migration to localhost

Tags: database, wordpress, migration, connection

I am trying to migrate a wp live site to localhost. I download and imported db, also all the files from FTP client etc. I have changed db settings ( password, user etc.) I also checkeg and changed all the things i need -> https://webnus.net/live-wordpress-site-to-localhost/  ( update database tables and changed domain to localhost etc.) but i am still getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ... Dont know what esle am I supposed to do. Thanks for any advice...

Comment: What do you use for running the server on localhost (for ex., XAMPP etc.)? Are you sure your local server is configured properly and the problem is on the WordPress side?

Comment: It's a bit odd, but  i am using MAMP on win... Have no idea where the problem could be. But fresh new wp site is working just fine. Only this bloody migration doesn't ...

Comment: You could try to connect your fresh wordpress to your imported DB, and if it works, import your wp-content folder ? you could find your issue doing this

Comment: @DanielaDrabkova First of all I would put something like `die("You are in the index file");` to the very beginning of the `index.php` file to check that your server is accessing WordPress's `index.php` file. Then I would try to enable all PHP errors with something like `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: WOOOW, it worked - i have spent 10 hours sorting this... i want to cry :D seriously. THANK YOU